# JavaFX фигура поверх фигуры

Tags: java, javafx

В приложении необходимо чтобы вторая кнопка была всегда поверх всех кнопок,остальные кнопки создаются динамически перекрывая кнопку Game(она позади рисунка). Можно ли каким-нибудь образом сделать ей привилегию постоянного нахождения поверх всех компонентов на форме?

Comment: http://s019.radikal.ru/i601/1704/23/92fa2c3dd5f1.png

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.